# N/A out certain rows in R using ifelse dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this

```
Type Species Letter Number Batch
  a     X      Al      1     H
  a     Y      Si      6     H

  b     Z      Mn      3     R
  b     Q      Qp      9     R

  c     L      Tw      10    R
  c     S      Rl      5     R
```

**Where I have used group_by(type)**
I want to write a statement that looks at the BATCH column, and if it is R, it will then look at the NUMBER column, and look at the lowest number between the two, and then set both the LETTER and NUMBER for that row to NA.
Not even sure if this is possible, but this is what it would look like in the end

```
Type Species Letter Number Batch
  a     X      Al      1     H
  a     Y      Si      6     H

  b     Z      NA      NA    R
  b     Q      Qp      9     R

  c     L      Tw      10    R
  c     S      NA      NA    R
```

Answer (score 4):

Another idea using `replace()` and `which.min()`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(Number = ifelse(Batch == "R", replace(Number, which.min(Number), NA), Number))
```

Essentially you can read it like this:

> Group `df` by `Type` then, if `Batch == "R"` replace the minimum
>   `Number` value in the group by `NA`, else, return the original
>   `Number` value

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#Groups: Type
#
#  Type Species Letter Number Batch
#1    a       X     Al      1     H
#2    a       Y     Si      6     H
#3    b       Z     Mn     NA     R
#4    b       Q     Qp      9     R
#5    c       L     Tw     10     R
#6    c       S     Rl     NA     R
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
df2 <- df[rep(row.names(df), 10e5),]

library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  Gregor = df2 %>%
    group_by(Type) %>%
    mutate(make_na = Batch == "R" & Number == min(Number),
           Number = ifelse(make_na, NA, Number),
           Letter = ifelse(make_na, NA, Letter)) %>%
    select(-make_na),
  Steven = df2 %>%
    group_by(Type) %>%
    mutate(Number = ifelse(Batch == "R", replace(Number, which.min(Number), NA), Number)),
  times = 10, unit = "relative")
```

[image]

```
# Unit: relative
#    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  Gregor 1.863925 2.230475 2.065081 2.220267 2.004923 1.919964    10   b
#  Steven 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy, just mapping your words to code. I create an intermediate column to mark the rows that need to be `NA`-ified, then I remove it at then end.

```
your_grouped_df %>%
mutate(make_na = ifelse(Batch == "R" & Number == min(Number), 1, 0),
       Number = ifelse(make_na == 1, NA, Number),
       Letter = ifelse(make_na == 1, NA, Letter)) %>%
select(-make_na)
```

We can simplify a little bit:

```
# same code as above, using TRUE/FALSE instead of 1/0
your_grouped_df %>%
mutate(make_na = ifelse(Batch == "R" & Number == min(Number), TRUE, FALSE),
       Number = ifelse(make_na, NA, Number),
       Letter = ifelse(make_na, NA, Letter)) %>%
select(-make_na)
```

Or even a little more, getting rid of the first `ifelse()` altogether.
Whenever you have `ifelse(..., TRUE, FALSE)`, the `ifelse()` is unnecessary, it's returning the same thing as its first argument

```
# make_na column is created directly as a logical column
your_grouped_df %>%
mutate(make_na = Batch == "R" & Number == min(Number),
       Number = ifelse(make_na, NA, Number),
       Letter = ifelse(make_na, NA, Letter)) %>%
select(-make_na)
```

Comment: Just one question, what are the 1,0 for ?

Comment: `ifelse`  has 3 arguments, (1) a condition, (2) the result if the condition is true, and (3) the result if the condition is false. The 1 and 0 are the true and false conditions, respectively. That `ifelse()` statement creates the column `make_na` and marks it 1 if the conditions are met and 0 otherwise. Because I used `1` inside `ifelse`, I test against 1 below, `ifelse(make_na == 1,...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I know you are looking for `dplyr` solution, but it might be worth looking also at `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

    setDT(df)[Batch=="R",`:=`(Letter=ifelse(Letter==Letter[which.min(Number)],"NA",Letter),Number=ifelse(Number==min(Number),as.integer(NA),Number)),by=Type]
   Type Species Letter Number Batch
1:    a       X     Al      1     H
2:    a       Y     Si      6     H
3:    b       Z     NA     NA     R
4:    b       Q     Qp      9     R
5:    c       L     Tw     10     R
6:    c       S     NA     NA     R
```

## Data

```
   df<-structure(list(Type = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"), Species = c("X", 
"Y", "Z", "Q", "L", "S"), Letter = c("Al", "Si", "Mn", "Qp", 
"Tw", "Rl"), Number = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 10L, 5L), Batch = c("H", 
"H", "R", "R", "R", "R")), .Names = c("Type", "Species", "Letter", 
"Number", "Batch"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```